# Column value not being added to table in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a form with a hidden field and a Request-> ip () value to get the ip of the user

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{Request::ip()}}" name="user_ip">
```

Laravel default registration system methods

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
        'telephone' => 'required|unique:users|min:5|max:25',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'recaptcha',
        'user_ip' => 'required|ip',
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'user_ip' => $data['user_ip'],
        'telephone' => Hash::make($data['telephone']),
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

When I do dd($data) or dd($request->all()), I see the ip, but for some reason it is not added to the base

Comment: did you add this field to `$fillable` on the Model?

Comment: Thank you. Why are such little things sometimes forgotten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it in 2 ways:

1. Add that field to fillables:

```
$fillable = ['name', 'email', ........., 'user_ip'];
```

2. Just do this, in this way, you don't have to add every field that you add to your migration:

```
$guarded = [];
```

I think second way is better than first!

Comment: don't use `guarded` use `fillable` "fillable" is the only thing that filters out what is mass assigned